# Minimalist way of sending plain text to another computer in osx/linux terminal

Tags: linux, macos, terminal

I'd like to find the simplest way of sending plain text messages to another host/ip address.
For example, I may run some commands in the terminal, such as

```
df -h
```

and I want to send the output to another computer/phone. I know I can of course do the copy/paste and use messages/emails, etc, but I'm looking for an elegant way of achieving this most efficiently directly in the terminal.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

With SSH, you could run the command directly on the remote and store the output locally, or vice versa. (Set up SSH keys to get rid of entering passwords.)

This would run `df -h` on `somehost` and store the output in `df-h-from-somehost.txt` on the local system:

```
ssh user@somehost 'df -h' > df-h-from-somehost.txt
```

And this would run `df -h` on the local host, and store the output in `df-h-from-otherhost.txt` on `somehost`:

```
df -h | ssh user@somehost 'cat > df-h-from-otherhost.txt'
```

Comment: Could you please explain why does it do after the pipe in option 2?

Comment: @JackeyOL, in the second, `ssh` connects to `somehost`, and runs the command `cat > df-h-from-otherhost.txt` there, on the remote system. `ssh` copies the input from the pipe to the remote host, and the `cat` on the remote copies the input from that end of the SSH connection to the file through the redirection. The remote command that SSH launches goes through the shell, so redirections like that work as usual.

Comment: @JackeyOL, note that there's a big difference between `ssh somehost 'somecmd > file.txt'` and `ssh somehost 'somecmd' > file.txt`! In the first, the redirection is within the quotes, and passed to the remote, in the second it happens on the local system.

Comment: @ikkachu For `ssh somehost 'somecmd' > file.txt`: does it tell the remote host to run somecmd (the command which is on remote host) and redirect the output to localhost.